# MySQL: query to sort data based on the attribute of another column

Tags: sql, mysql, pivot

So, coming up with a title for this is difficult

```
SELECT Date(p.born_at), SUM(p.value) as 'total_value_for_day'
FROM puppies as p
WHERE p.status = 2
GROUP BY DATE(p.born_at);
```

So, this gives a 2 column result.

What I want is this:

columns:

```
date | status = 1 | status = 2 | status = 3
DATA!!!
```

is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you clarify the result you want?  It looks like you want 4 columns, the first is the date, and for the next three columns, you want the data for the matching status.  So if status = 3, for example, populate data in that column.  Is that correct?  It would really clarify your question if you gave an example output with made-up data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Date(p.born_at), 
SUM(case when status = 1 then p.value end) as 'status = 1',
SUM(case when status = 2 then p.value end) as 'status = 2',
SUM(case when status = 3 then p.value end) as 'status = 3'
FROM puppies as p
WHERE p.status in(1,2,3)
GROUP BY DATE(p.born_at);
```

Comment: is it better to use the WHERE or not use the WHERE?

Comment: Depends on your data! Using the `WHERE` will potentially avoid processing unnecessary rows if you have ones where status is not 1,2, or 3. If all of the rows have one of those values then it would probably be best to remove it to avoid a redundant check.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Date(born_at), 
    SUM(case when Status = 1 then value else 0 end) as 'status = 1',
    SUM(case when Status = 2 then value else 0 end) as 'status = 2',
    SUM(case when Status = 3 then value else 0 end) as 'status = 3' 
FROM puppies 
GROUP BY DATE(born_at);
```

Comment: is it better to use the WHERE or not use the WHERE?

Comment: If you have more than 3 possible statuses, I would use a WHERE clause. It is unclear from your question...

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
   DATE(p.born_at)
   , SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN p.value END) AS 'Status = 1'
   , SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 2 THEN p.value END) AS 'Status = 2'
   , SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 3 THEN p.value END) AS 'Status = 3'
FROM puppies AS p
WHERE p.status IN(1, 2, 3)
GROUP BY DATE(p.born_at);
```